# Orchard 1.8 and reCaptcha not allowing theme changes

Tags: recaptcha, orchardcms-1.8

I'm simply trying to change the theme for reCaptcha using globally settings through Settings > Spam. I can add the keys no problem, however cannot change the theme to 'clean' from say 'red'?

Orchard Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the View is under the EditorTemplates folder and its called `Parts.ReCaptcha.Fields.cshtml` . Will have a look properly when i have a chance to see exactly why is there or is should file a bug.  
have never tried to override it, actually.
Anyways, edit your view to have something like this, thats how i did it for a client.

```
@model Orchard.AntiSpam.ViewModels.ReCaptchaPartEditViewModel

@{
    using (Script.Head())
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = { theme: 'clean' };
        </script>
    }
}

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=@Model.PublicKey"></script>
  <noscript>
     <iframe src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=@Model.PublicKey" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
     <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
     </textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
  </noscript>
```

You are only adding the script bit:

```
@{
    using (Script.Head())
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var RecaptchaOptions = { theme: 'clean' };
        </script>
    }
}
```